# CE Image - Source image is not readable or does not exist

Tags: ce-image

We moved a site into a sub folder while we upgrade it, so the site is now at: mysite.com/2014/ .  Everything seems to be ok, except CE Image is not returning any images.  I've tried all variations on the CE Image tags, but we get nothing.  I've checked that the folders have 777 permissions.  The code below should be returning the image url:

```
<img src="{exp:ce_img:single src='{event_image}' width='225' height='225' crop='yes' allow_scale_larger='yes' url_only='yes'}" alt="{title}" />
```

But all I get is:

```
<img src="" alt="Ferris wheel">
```

I've switched on debugging and get the following errors:

***  CE Image debug: Base path: '/chroot/home/winter14/public_html/'
(0.728373 / 24.88MB)

CE Image debug: Base path: '/home/winter14/public_html/2014/'
(0.806898 / 27.42MB)

***  CE Image debug: Source image: 'http://www.example.com/2014/uploads/events/ice.jpg', Fallback image: ''
(0.806906 / 27.42MB)

***  CE Image debug: Source image is not readable or does not exist: '/2014/uploads/events/ice.jpg'.

(0.806914 / 27.42MB)

***  CE Image debug: Fallback source image is not readable or does not exist: ''.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to reset all your file upload paths and urls.
this setting also comes in handy.

```
$config['ce_image_cache_dir'] = '/images/made/';
```

http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/configuration

Also, as Blatant says, running the sync on the file upload prefs has been known to make everything better.

what does this give you?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, simple answers first...

Following relocation, did you update all your settings paths (hint: use [ReeLocate](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reelocate) for a quick win here)?

After this, did you re-sycronise all your upload directories? (Content > Files > File Upload Preferences > Syncronise (Column) )????

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. I should have mentioned that, all upload paths have being checked and folders synchronised.  If i leave out the CE Image tags and just put the field name in, the image appears ok.

Comment: Ok cool, like I say gotta cover the simple answers first. This is where I have to defer to someone with more recent CE experiance than I though, as you say disabling CE makes it work so it'll be CEImage centric, and its been a long time since I had a sandbox with this module in it. Jim might well be able to add further info.